# What is the best way to create a new Play! 2.1 module?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

As of Play 2.0, it appears that there is no longer a way of creating a module for an existing Play application, other than by creating a new Play application. Having searched around a bit, I came across [these instructions](http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=363), which indicate that I must (or at least should) delete any routes created in the new module (application), and that the module's application.conf file is really just a stub that is required in order for the module to be recognized as a Play application.

I am new to Play, but apparently there used to be a console command ('new-module') for generating a module, which presumably created only those files which were needed for the module to be discovered by the application. It seems to me like it would still be useful to be able to quickly create a new module in this way, especially if registering a new module from the console also added the module to your build, and to the repository of your choice, thus removing the requirement for (as much) manual wiring.

I would also like to be able to maintain Play modules upon which my application depends as part of the same codebase/build, such that, when I make changes to a module, they are picked up at application compile time (for example, when play is ~ running and and a changed file is saved). Does this already happen with modules registered as dependencies, or must I rebuild modules independently of my application?

Because I am a newcomer, I'm not positive that there *isn't* a way to do accomplish these tasks in an automated manner. There is a chapter on packages and modules listed in the [Play for Scala book](http://www.manning.com/hilton/) (Part III, chapter 9), but the book is not yet complete and that chapter is, unfortunately, yet unwritten.

If an experienced Play! developer would be so kind as to either confirm that the instructions to which I linked above are still the recommended procedure for creating a module and registering/maintaining it as a dependency, or else list a better procedure, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the information is valid.

To Play 2.x there is no difference between a regular library and a Play module (a library which itself depends on the play library jar).

The part about the routes file is still valid, but they introduced 'Sub-Router composition' to give you some extra freedom (search for 'Allow more modularization for your projects' on the [highlight page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Highlights#Allow%20more%20modularization%20for%20your%20projects)).

Libraries (and thus Play modules) are referenced in the `Build.scala` file with version, for example:

```
"play.modules.mailer" %% "play-mailer" % "1.1.0"
```

If you are developing a module yourself you could use the 'publish-local' command to make sure other projects on your computer can find the dependency. Because modules are essentially versioned libraries you need to compile them separately from your application. However no-one is preventing you from running scripts to automate things.